# Converting RGB pixels to Grayscale in Python. No matplot or PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, rgb, grayscale

I have a homework assignment I'm desperate to figure out. We've only spent two lecture days on opencv so I'm going in blind with this.

The assignment is to convert an RGB img to grayscale using the luminance formula 0.02126*R+0.7152*G+0.0722*B

So the type of each pixel should be the same as the original image. We're not allowed to use matplot or PIL which is what I've seen a lot of trying to figure this thing out.

The code I have now outputs just a gray image. So instead of graySCALE, it's only gray. I'm so lost, please help.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def togray():
    img = cv2.imread("fruits.jpg")
    cv2.imshow('Original',img)
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    img2 = np.ndarray (shape=(height,width,))
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            img2[i,j]=(0*0.2126 + 0.7152*1 + 0.0722*2)

    cv2.imshow('Grayscale',img2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

togray()
```

Comment: In your loop, you're setting all `i,j` coordinates to the exact same value: `(0*0.2126 + 0.7152*1 + 0.0722*2)`. I haven't used this package, but I imagine you need r, g, and b values in place of 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: @Julien now my output is just a smaller gray box.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `img2 = 0.02126*img[:,:,2] + 0.7152*img[:, :,1] + 0.0722*img[:,:,0]`

The comment by Julien was wrong for two reasons: (i) The shape of an image is `(m, n, 3)` in opencv. This explains why that indexing gives you a smaller box. (ii) opencv channels are BGR, not RGB, so you need to swap the 2 and the 0 indices as I did here. (The actual result should not change too much just considering how small the R and B terms contribute).

Comment: @Julien no worries! just wanted to explain to op why outcome was what it was

Comment: @dimgawd thanks for the response. However, running that crashes my code every time.

Comment: @dimgawd error: /Users/vagrant/workspace/Buildsystem/test/pisi/tmp/opencv-3.2.0-4/work/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow 
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /Users/vagrant/workspace/Buildsystem/test/pisi/tmp/opencv-3.2.0-4/work/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 304

Comment: @dimgawd but in the terminal there is no error. I have to force quit python. It then says Terminated: 15

Comment: that sounds more like the image passed had height and width 0, check always the shape to make sure that at least the arrays are consistent ( `print (img2.shape)` )